# Why do pdflatex and latex LNCS outputs look different?

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I've found that using embedded postscript (eps) with the `pdflatex` command, as opposed to the `latex` command, may require more effort; and potentially insecure write18 permissions with cygwin. No problem, I thought, I can just use `latex`. However, the two give different results.

I made a test by unzipping the Springer LNCS file [llncs2e.zip](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip). In the first case I used:

```
pdflatex llncs.dem && pdflatex llncs.dem
```

In the second case I used:

```
latex llncs.dem && latex llncs.dem && dvipdf llncs.dvi
```

In the second case I find that the bottom margin appears very large, while the top margin is too small; and don't think this looks acceptable. I'm not looking for a way to fix the margins, but would like to know where I went wrong in assuming that both routes would produce identical output.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Both files look identical. You should provide some more information on the OS and LateX installation you use. Maybe you could post a picture to show what happens in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `llncs` class should work just like the standard `article` class. You can specify the `a4paper` option to get A4 paper size, or omit it to get the letter paper size.

With pdflatex, this is all that you need.

With latex + dvips + ps2pdf, you will *also* need to specify the correct paper size on the dvips command line, for example, `dvips -t a4`. The `dvipdf` tool seems to be similar.

---

Note that dvips might or might not accidentally produce the correct paper size, depending on the configuration of your system. It might be best not to count on it; always specify the paper size on the command line, or you will have surprises when you try to compile it on another computer.

---

Finally, the LNCS books of course do not have the physical paper size of A4 or letter. If you want to produce a PDF file with a paper size that matches the final printed book, [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/publ-tips/#paperformat) you can find a very useful trick: use pdflatex and specify

```
\pdfpagesattr{/CropBox [92 112 523 778]}
```

Comment: So, the output of pdflatex uses a default papersize? And dvipdf will probably have a switch to set that. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @user4417: AFAIK: pdflatex should use the paper size selected in the Latex source code, that is, A4 for `a4paper` and letter otherwise. dvipdf will ignore the Latex source code; it will use a default setting that depends on your system configuration. If you want to use dvipdf, use the right command line switch to override the default.

Comment: I don't know where the paper size is selected in llncs.dem. I also can't find any command line switches for dvipdf which will take a4paper. I think I will just move to use pdflatex, and use epstopdf in my makefiles.

Comment: IIRC, `llncs` delegates the paper size selection to the `article` class, which uses letter by default and A4 with the `a4paper` option. You can use `dvips` + `ps2pdf` instead of `dvipdf`, so that you can select the paper size, or you can edit the `dvipdf` script (it is a short shell script that invokes `dvips`).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see neither the class nor set the (pdf) paper size. Perhaps you get letterpaper in one case. Apart from this: all the different routes to pdf (pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf, latex+dvipdfmx, latex +...) can give different results.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying cause are different coordinate-system conventions: Both DVI and PostScript have the origin in the top-left corner of the page, whereas PDF unfortunately moved it to the bottom-left corner.

So any program that converts between PostScript and PDF (or DVI and PDF) has to assume a paper height, and shift all coordinates by that height. Unfortunately, there are still two different commonly-used default paper heights: [ISO A4](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/iso-paper.html) (297 mm) and U.S. Letter (279 mm). If one program assumes A4 and the other U.S. Letter, your text will move up or down by 297 mm - 279 mm = 18 mm. As others have already explained, setting the paper size consistently (preferably to the one that the document will ultimately be printed on) will fix this.